# Is there a way that I can make people have to input an administrators password to change the desktop background?

Tags: unity-2d, administration

I have a problem of lots of people changing my desktop background.  Is there a way that I can make people have to input an administrators password to change the desktop background.  I am running ubuntu 12.04 lts with unity 2d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your are doing and why they change your desktop background but you could let the other users only use the 'guest session' *(a default feature -> the login screen shows a guest session login button)* or create a separate user account for them *(System Settings -> User Accounts)*.

#### Another solution but more a dirty hack:

You could set the background using a cronjob every ~5 min:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png"`

Comment: @ Paradiesstaub The problem is that people are changing the desktop background on school computers to really bad or annoying backgrounds and I want to lock it on the default background

Comment: I haven't found a good solution (the dconfig lock stuff broke the system), only a hack. You could set the background using a cronjob every ~5 min: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png"`

Comment: @ Paradiesstaub make that an answer.